# Поиск и подсчёт количества элементов в массиве js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Доброй ночи. Есть многомерный массив `arr[[],[],[]]`, состоящий из `false` и `true`, подскажите каким методом получить количество `true` в массиве?

Comment: циклами и рекурсией

Comment: а можно по-точнее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как и сказал Igor, циклы и рекурсия :

```js
var ar = [
  [true, false, true],
  [true, false, false],
  [true, false, true],
  [true, true, true],
  [false, false, true],
  [true, false],
  true,
  false, [true, false]
];

function calculate(array) {
  var res = {
    'false': 0,
    'true': 0
  };

  count(array);
  return res;

  function count(arr) {
    arr.forEach(e => {
      if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        count(e);
      } else {
        res['false'] += e ? 0 : 1;
        res['true'] += e ? 1 : 0;
      }
    });
  };
};

console.log(calculate(ar));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё как вариант используя функцию [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const countTrue = arrayOrElement =>
  Array.isArray(arrayOrElement)
    ? arrayOrElement.reduce((number, element) => number + countTrue(element), 0)
    : (arrayOrElement ? 1 : 0);
```

То же для подсчёта произвольных элементов:

```
const countValues = (arrayOrElement, valueToCount) =>
  Array.isArray(arrayOrElement)
    ? arrayOrElement.reduce((number, element) => number + countValues(element, valueToCount), 0)
    : (arrayOrElement === valueToCount ? 1 : 0);
```

Сниппет для обоих вариантов:

```js
let array = [
  [true, false, true, false],
  [true, [false, [false, []]]],
  [[[[true]]]],
  [[[true], true], true],
  true,
  false,
  [[[[]]]]
];

const countTrue = arrayOrElement =>
  Array.isArray(arrayOrElement)
    ? arrayOrElement.reduce((number, element) => number + countTrue(element), 0)
    : (arrayOrElement ? 1 : 0);
console.log(countTrue(array));

const countValues = (arrayOrElement, valueToCount) =>
  Array.isArray(arrayOrElement)
    ? arrayOrElement.reduce((number, element) => number + countValues(element, valueToCount), 0)
    : (arrayOrElement === valueToCount ? 1 : 0);
console.log(countValues(array, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто количество то можно и так:

```js
var arr = [
    [true, false, true],
    [true, false, false],
    [true, false, true],
    [true, true, true],
    [false, false, true],
    [true, false],
    true,
    false, [true, false]
];
let newArr = arr.join().split(',');
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (newArr[i] == "true") {
        count++;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```